How to add JSDoc documentation to a re-exported namespace in TypeScript?
I have a module that re-exports another module as a namespace:
export * as Foo from "bar";

I want to add documentation to the exported namespace so when it is imported, some description of the namespace shows up in the IDE. I tried things like
/** blah blah blah */
export * as Foo from "bar";

---

import * as Foo from "bar";
/** blah blah blah */
export { Foo };

---

import * as Foo from "bar";
export {
  /** blah blah blah */
  Foo
};

None of these worked (at least, not in VS Code).
The only way I could make it work is this:
import * as _Foo from "bar";
/** blah blah blah */
export const Foo = _Foo;

However, that's an unnecessary assignment, which I don't really like.
Is it possible to do this directly, without an extra variable somehow?
